# Weird SendKeys observation into Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

How an external software can help the VB.NET SendKeys to perform correctly ?

On Windows 7 (UAC=Off), `Sendkeys.Send(string)` runs as fast as windows XP when writing the string into Notepad (for example).

On Windows 7 (UAC=On), with the app.config set to `<add key="Sendkeys" value="SendInput"/>`, the `Sendkeys.Send(string)` is written very slowly into Notepad.

I loaded the software http://www.phraseexpress.com/ which writes strings very fast into Notepad.

But the weird thing is when that software is loaded, the `Sendkeys.Send(string)` from VB is also written very fast into Notepad when used!

Once the software is unloaded, the VB `Sendkeys.Send(string)` recover the slow process writing into Notepad.

So there is a setting for sure that could be done into VB to enhance Sendkeys. Is there any path I could explore into VB to help me resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what PhraseExpress does, but check out this:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=560647

"Apparently, when Speech Recognition is running, Sendkeys is very fast."

It's a strange connection worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks rskar, I tried Speech Recognition with no apparent results.